# Convert coordinates to a place name

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

I am using the HTML5 Geolocation API to find the longitude and the latitude from the users of my site. This works, but now I would like to show on the screen "You currently are in ...". So I need to convert these coordinates I get from the Geolocation API to a place name.

I tried a bit with Google Maps API, but I didn't get it working.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Google Maps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) have what seems to be a complete [reverse geocoding example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding). (Note that this is the new V3 API!)